# I don’t have read permissions on a file but I can read it

Tags: permissions, group, gid

I have a file owned by a different user with permissions 440. When I do ‘groups’ I don’t belong to the group of the file, but when I do ‘groups my_username’ I do.

Why am I able to open the file if my current shell does not have access to the group?

Comment: I'm guessing the output of `groups` is cached by your shell and is stale. The shell's cache doesn't influence access checks performed by the kernel.

Comment: @D.SM: What shell has `groups` as a builtin?  Is there some other way that the shell could cache the output of `groups`?

Comment: Maybe not the shell, but there is still a cache somewhere.

Comment: What does `id` show?